# Watin does not open reflexive questions done in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, watin

I have an AJAX page that has a series of reflexive questions(ie,  you answer the parent question and a second question "unhides" from the page), but Watin fails to unhide the child question.  The parent question consists of Yes and No radio questions.  If I click the radio button manually, it does unhide the child question.

I tried in Watin all the following:

```
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).MouseDown();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).MouseUp();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).Checked = true;
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).Focus();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).KeyPress();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).KeyDown();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).MouseEnter();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).Blur();
tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).Change();
```

I know you might suggest then to do a FireEvent(),  but there I don't see "onclick()" or anything else that seems to be calling a Javascript function when the radio buttons get clicked.   Has anybody dealt with AJAX reflexive questions on their web application and how do they deal with such in Watin?   Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: 2 things: tr.RadioButton(Find.ByLabelText(xe.Value)).Click(); and can you give us some html code or a link to an example?

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a link to a definition of "Ajax reflexive question", because it doesn't come up on a http://www.asp.net/search ?

What are you using to see if there are any jQueries being called?  I've been using FireQuery with Firebug on Firefix, because otherwise I cannot tell from the HTML alone if I need to do something extra in order to trigger the change.

I am guessing that these Elements of yours will need to be triggered through JavaScript in order for the change to occur, which has been talked about in a number of threads here.

Comment: @t3hn00b I used the Click(), but no luck. Here is a snippet of the HTML that has the radio buttons -    <DIV style="FLOAT: left" id=ctl00_interfaceContent_container_94459 class="Field_container CURRENTLYLICENSED">
<DIV id=ctl00_interfaceContent_labels_94459 class=labels><LABEL for=ctl00_interfaceContent_94459>Do you hold an active resident insurance license? </LABEL><SPAN class=requiredField>*</SPAN> </DIV>
<DIV id=ctl00_interfaceContent_inputs_94459 class=inputs>
<TABLE id=ctl00_interfaceContent_94459 class=Currentlylicensed border=0 jQuery1520836702859528752="7"> Parker,Will try FireQuery